# How to describe to assign the comment key(;) as trigger?

Tags: autohotkey

How to describe to assign the comment key(;) as trigger?

I Want to IME ON with the comment key(;). However, the key(;) change the line to comment statement.

`.ahk` I guessed,bellow.

```
; The left alt key to IME OFF, below
LAlt up::
    if (A_PriorHotkey == "*~LAlt")
    {
        IME_SET(0)
    }
    Return

; only ";" key to IME ON ( I want)
; up::   ← First ";" proceeded as comment. I want it to re-assign to as triger.
    if (A_PriorHotkey == "*~???")
    {
        IME_SET(1)
    }
    Return
```

Comment: Try replacing `;` by its [scan code](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: `vkBBsc027` or `vkBB`??

Comment: Try `sc027 up::` as first, then `sc027vkBB up::` and so on.

Comment: `sc027 up:: IME_SET(1)` should work

Comment: Dear user3419297, really? I could not understand to realize my wish. Please give me the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it in a standalone script (Use only this code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere):

```
LAlt up:: 
; MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey%
IME_SET(0)
return

sc027 up:: 
; MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey%
IME_SET(1)
return

; Add here the IME_SET() function
```

Comment: Dear user3419297, Thank you very much!. 'sc027 up' could hook the key';'.

Comment: >> Caution!? The above code was I want (maybe). Please read context of this thread whether you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will not realize. Because ;(semicolon) is not modifier but normal input.

---

Current(ON THE WAY) my code for OneMix4S.
Thank you very much a lot of example which users published, I reffered.

```
; Left Alt of space key turns IME OFF
$LAlt::
    startTime := A_TickCount
    KeyWait, LAlt
    keyPressDuration := A_TickCount - startTime
    If (A_ThisHotkey == "$LAlt" and keyPressDuration < 200) {
        ; Send,{vk0D}
        IME_SET(0)
        ; Send,{vkF3}
    }
    Return

; LAlt + j turns on IME ON
~LAlt & j::
    ; if (A_PriorHotkey == "*~sc027")
    {
        IME_SET(1)
    }
    Return

; Below convert to push ESC key.
~LAlt & vkBB up::
    ; if (A_PriorHotkey == "*~sc027")
    {
        ; IME_SET(1)
        Send,{Esc}
    }
    Return
```